# How to display an image if it exists or a default if it doesn't

Tags: laravel, lumen

Trying to figure out how to display an image if it exists, or a default if it doesn't. Heres what I have so far, but the statement checking for the file doesn't seem to be working:

```
@if (file_exists(public_path('img/{{ $product->sku }}.jpg')))
    <img src="img/{{$product->sku}}.jpg">
@else
    <img src="img/logo.gif">
@endif
```

Heres my full blade code. Everything works except the image:

```
<div class="products-gallery">
    <h2>{{$product->prd->description_long}}</h2>
    <p><strong>ITEM SKU:</strong> {{$product->sku}}</p>  
    <p><strong>PRICE:</strong> {{$product->prd->Jobber}}</p>
    @if (file_exists(public_path('img/{{$product->sku}}.jpg')))
        <img src="img/{{$product->sku}}.jpg">
    @else
        <img src="img/logo.gif">
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I would print out `public_path('img/{{ $product->sku }}.jpg'))` and make sure it's pointing at the right directory. Also make sure that directory and file have read access.

Comment: I got `/Users/ekko207/Documents/GitHub/api.vogtlandna/public/img/sku); ?>.jpg` so I'm not sure how to make the sku come in correctly

Comment: You should be able to do `{{ public_path('img/' . $product->sku . '.jpg')) }}`

Comment: Gives me an error `Undefined variable: product `

Comment: what about just `{{ $product->sku }}`? If `$product` is actually undefined, that would be why your code isn't working.

Comment: `{{ $product->sku }}` works everywhere else, just not when I try adding it to an image source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although you asked about `Laravel` implementation, you should also be aware you can do it in pure javascript and avoid verifying the existence of the file:

```
<img src="img/{{$product->sku}}.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='img/logo.gif';" />
```

Less code to write and this will also handle other errors (such as file exists but corrupted).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helps tremendously! You are awesome! Thank you!

Comment: how about it external image? for example if it was fb profile pic?

Comment: @ClintonCanarias It should work the same for external images as well

Answer (score 0):

use the asset('/img/' . $product->sku . '.jpg') method

Comment: I get `Call to undefined function asset()` when trying to use asset

Comment: i edited below, btw are you using the newest version of laravel?

Comment: Its Lumen, but it should be the latest version. I didn't set it up initially so I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (file_exists(public_path().'/img/'.$product->sku))
    <img src="{{ asset('img/'.$product->sku) }}">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.gif') }}">
@endif
```

The image extension(as you mentioned `.jpg`) saves by default when you upload. Hope it helps!

Comment: Call to undefined function asset()